# Get Users of specific group id

Tags: rest, api, onelogin

How to fetch all users based on specific group id?

API URL : https://api.us.onelogin.com/api/1/users

I want to fetch user via below URL

API URL : https://api.us.onelogin.com/api/1/users?group_id=xxx